# python , output from csv format to json from

Tags: python, json, csv, tweets

i have the code output  in csv fromat, i tried to convert it to json but it is converted with some error in json file.  here is csv code . i will be thankful if you  tell me how to convert the output into json instead of csv with proper output json format.

thank you

```
print >> out, 'text '
rows = zip(texts)

from csv import writer
csv = writer(out)

for row in rows:
    values = [(value.encode('utf8') if hasattr(value, 'encode') else value) for value in row]
    csv.writerow(values)

out.close()
```

Comment: What error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Json should have defined data structure. I am using the following structure as an example:

```
[{"title" : "Gone with the wind", "description" : "A book"},
 {"title" : "White Fang", "description" : "A book"},
 {"title" : "Dracula", "description" : "A book"},
 {"title" : "Van Helsing", "description" : "A movie"},
 ...]
```

And here is the code for converting that into a json array object, and write into file:

```
# I'm not sure what you are doing here, but zip returns a list of tuples
# For example: [("Gone with the wind", "A book"), ("Van Helsing", "A movie")...]
rows = zip(texts) 

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    data = list()
    for title, desc in rows: # According to your tuple
        data.append(dict(title=title, description=desc))
    json.dump(data, f) # Write the list into the output file
```